# Do Windows RIO sockets pay attention to the TCP PSH flag on the receive side?

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, winsock2

I'm looking for some insider details on how Windows RIO sockets interact with TCP. In my experimentation, I've gathered that on the sending side, each individual RIOBUF segment provided to RIOSend() seems to get book-ended with the TCP PSH flag. However, on the receiving side, I'm not seeing any discernible use of the PSH flag. The RIOBUF segments posted via RIOReceive() seem to complete immediately once some data flows in whether the PSH flag has been received or not. Quite often i'll find that each receive segment completes containing the contents of one TCP packet. I'm just looking for some confirmation here so I can make sure to slice up my receive buffer such that it will be utilized to its fullest. Does anyone happen to know the details of what triggers a receive buffer completion when a RIO socket is used with TCP? Does a RIO receiver make use of the push flag at all? If not, is it generally a better strategy to segment my receive buffer so that each RIOBUF has a length equal to the TCP MSS to avoid gaps in the registered buffer?

Comment: Nobody does. The TCP PSH flag was intended to provide an interrupt-like facility which never eventuated.

Comment: @user207421 - It seems to be used by WSARecv() to short circuit the completion of the receive buffer. My testing aligns with that. That's also why that interface accepts MSG_PUSH_IMMEDIATE as an option to ignore the push flag. RIO sockets are a different beast though, there is no such option.